# What does the word 'cultivation' seen in many Chinese manhua refer to?

Tags: manga-production, terminology

What does the word cultivation mean in Chinese media?

There seems to be legion of titles out there with some variation of this phrase,
e.g. urban cultivator, immortal cultivator, cultivator chat group, ad infinitum.

Comment: Looks like this is called [Xianxia novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xianxia_novel) which is related to [Xian in Taoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xian_(Taoism)) and related to "cultivation" (but I can't expand more than this since this is out of my expertise at all, anyone feels free to expand and post the answer...)

Comment: Also. I found [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ub1cpd2Qg90) explaining this concept in Chinese fantasy novels, which I believe is more related. (Still don't have time to write a proper answer...)